# I'm having trouble with auto complete

Tags: c#, linq, autocomplete

thanks for reading my question
i'm trying to set auto complete for a text box and  i don't get what i wanted i guess my linq must have some sort of problem
here's my codes

```
 private AutoCompleteStringCollection GetLinqDataSourceForString(string p)
    {
        var c = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        c.Add(p + Getauto(txtSearch.Text));
        return c;
    }

private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtSearch.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        txtSearch.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        txtSearch.AutoCompleteCustomSource = GetLinqDataSourceForString(txtSearch.Text);
    }
```

and here's my linq which is supposed to get data from Data Base

```
    public string AutoUpdate(string _search)
    {
        using (var context = new Phone_BookEntities1())
        {
            var c = (from d in context.Cantacts
                     where d.Cantact1 == _search
                     select d.Cantact1).SingleOrDefault();
            return c;
        }
     }
```

where is my problem?
please  help,Tnx

Comment: What isn't working? errors? wrong results?

Comment: @sayse it brings back the name and what we add to txtsearch.text EG:if we write (cat) it will type (catcat) and it won't give us any option when we type (c) its supposed to bring cat but it won't and you have to type all of the word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if we write (cat) it will type (catcat)

Well `p + Getauto(txtSearch.Text)` explains that, you probably don't want to be appending `p` here and `Getauto` should be using `p` instead

> and it won't give us any option when we type (c) its supposed to bring cat but it won't and you have to type all of the word

Well your `where` is doing a complete comparison

```
where d.Cantact1 == _search
```

this probably needs to use [`StartsWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
where d.Cantact1.StartsWith(_search)
```

Comment: thank you so much i'm struggling  with it since yesterday

Comment: @MostafaBouzari - No worries, have fun!

Comment: now i get two run time errors first({"Sequence contains more than one element"} == System.InvalidOperationException )  when there is more than once it occurred,,,,,second one (System.AccessViolationException inner exception => Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.)

Comment: now i get two run time errors first({"Sequence contains more than one element"} == System.InvalidOperationException )  when there is more than once it occurred,,,,,second one (System.AccessViolationException inner exception => Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.)

Comment: @MostafaBouzari - If you have another question, you should ask it as a new question